# Linkout suggestion is not showing to Alpha/Beta tester on Google Assistant using Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using link out suggestion on my bot in some of my intents and my bot is deployed to my testers on google assistant using `dialogflow`.
But link-out suggestion is not displaying to my testers but its displaying on my developer account.
So I want to know would it be working fine for all users when i deploy my bot into the production enviorment or there is something i am missing in my bot to make it work?

Thank you

Comment: Can you update this question to include your fulfillment code?

Comment: I am making Static FAQ bot . In that i am not using any webhook . Its just static bot. @MaxWiederholt

Comment: This is still a problem.

Comment: This is still a problem - any resolution?

Comment: Nope I guess they have removed this link out suggestion. But they have kept in basic cards response